# CakePHP 3.0 how to write a model without table?

Tags: php, model, cakephp-3.0

I would like to write a business logic for my application. So I need to use a model. How to use a model without a table and don't affect on any other functionalities.

I used the `$this->_table=false` inside the `Table` class. When enable the debug mode. The debug Log not working?

Can you plz suggest me how to implement?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is now called a "[modelless form](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html)".

Comment: can you tell how you find this setting `$this->_table=false` for cakephp 3

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3.0 not support this feature.
You can read this post https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5390

Comment: This answer doesn't _seem_ to answer OP's question, but it is in fact the correct answer. The linked discussion is about CakePHP 3 model-less _forms_, whereas OP's question is about table-less _models_ - but the underlying feature is the same, and has been removed in 3.x because it doesn't fit the context of ORM.